# Rails Rspec tests only intermittently recognizing polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I am in the process of updating a very old legacy app from Rails 3 to Rails 4.2 (I know, I know). Our structure is that we have a models gem, a gem for spec factories, and multiple apps that use both of these gems. I'm currently working in one of these other apps and trying to fix specs.

I've come across this odd problem that I've spent days on. I can't find any answers online, and everything I've come across on Stack Overflow is not fully relatable to this issue.

The issue is this: I have multiple specs failing where a polymorphic association is failing only intermittently. So the association itself is working, but when running the test as a whole file, the polymorphic association fails **sometimes**. I have a specific file I've been running while working on this that has 3 examples, which are always run randomly, and it's always the second example that fails on this polymorphic association - that calling `message.recipient` returns that `recipient` is nil. And again, the first example always passes and the `recipient` is returned.

Here's the setup:

```
class Message
  belongs_to :recipient, polymorphic: true
end

class Membership
end
```

`Message` has already had the `recipient_id` and `recipient_type` on the table, which obviously previously to this upgrade was working correctly and calling `message.recipient` worked appropriately, but this is now where it's failing.

These tests I'm running are in, let's say `App1`, which is using the `Factory` gem of ours and the `Models` gem as well. This particular spec is a `job` spec, that runs through a job, but then of course ends up in the `Message` model in the `Models` gem, trying to do some work on the message, and calls `message.recipient` and gets `recipient` as nil. `Reload` does not work.

I've tried:

- Reloaded the `message` at many different points in the job process, but didn't work.
- Rewriting the specs (ie context changes, `let` vs `let!` changes), but that did not fix it.
- I ran the same types of test on the model `Message` itself in the `Models` gem specs, and it works fine.

To me, it seems as though this is an issue of communication between the gems and the app itself and the loading of the polymorphic associations for each individual spec, but despite going through all the configs and trying to make some changes I have not been able to pinpoint the issue, although it's obviously possible that I missed something here. I had begun to think this was purely an issue in our Factory gem, but the `message` instance not being created via the Factory, although in an entirely different spec that is exhibiting the same behavior, the object that is failing **is** being created in the Factory. So because of that, it seems the issue is simply between the polymorphic association being loaded correctly before each spec.

ETA:
We *are* using Spork, and we have this in `spec_helper.rb`, although this is existing code and not new to the upgrade

```
Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
  FactoryBot.reload
  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
  Dir[Rails.root + 'app/jobs/*.rb'].map {|f| File.basename(f, '.*').camelize.constantize }
end
```

Rails 4.2

rspec-rails 3.9.1

Ruby 2.3.6

Comment: 1/ What happens if you remove the FactoryBot reload in the Spork config?

2/ I'd be curious to see your factories